# Json to custom objekt in Python

Tags: python, json, object

So I got a problem that I don't know how to solve.

I want to load objects from JSON files and convert them into a specific object in python.
For example, I got some JSON like this:

```
{
   "Class1":{
        "name":"str",
        "value":float,
        "description":"str",
        etc.
        },

   "Class2":{
        "name":"str",
        "value":float,
        "description":"str"
        }
}
```

And some Python code like this:

```
class Class1:
    name:str
    value:float
    description:str

class Class2(Class1):
    def someMethod(self):
        pass
```

How can I turn this in the easiest way possible in the class it belongs to?

I already found some solutions online but they would require a custom encoder for each class. But I want something like one function which creates all objects.

Comment: note that `"value":float` is not valid JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) should do the job .
The constructor of a dataclass can handle data easily.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Class1:
    name:str
    value:float
    description:str

@dataclass
class Class2(Class1):
    def someMethod(self):
        pass

data ={
   "Class1":{
        "name":"str",
        "value":1.0,
        "description":"str",
         },

   "Class2":{
        "name":"str",
        "value":2.0,
        "description":"str"
        }
}


for k, vals in data.items():
    print(locals()[k](**vals))

# Class1(name='str', value=1.0, description='str')
# Class2(name='str', value=2.0, description='str')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) that is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dataclasses` as mentioned already by Glauco. If you intend to generate them from the json, in the style you mentioned, below is an example appraoch.

```
from dataclasses import make_dataclass
from pydoc import locate

definitions = {
    "Class1": {
        "name": "str",
        "value": "float",
        "description": "str",
    },

    "Class2": {
        "name": "str",
        "value": "float",
        "description": "str"
    }
}


def make_class(name, definition):
    def_fields = [(name, locate(typ)) for name, typ in definition.items()]
    return make_dataclass(name, def_fields)


classes = [make_class(name, definition) for name, definition in definitions.items()]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't really get what the make_class function does. Does it create a whole new dataclass from the json?

Comment: Yes it will. Not sure, If I understood your question wrongly.

Comment: I tried to load only the data from the json and not create a new class. But it will be useful to know that this is possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use dataclass

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
data = {
   "clazz_1":{
        "name":"jack",
        "value":12.5,
        "description":"desc1",
        },

   "clazz_2":{
        "name":"jim",
        "value":45.77,
        "description":"desc2"
        }
}
@dataclass
class A:
  name:str
  value: float
  description: str


@dataclass
class B:
  name:str
  value: float
  description: str

@dataclass
class Parent:
  clazz_1: A
  clazz_2: B 


p: Parent = Parent(**data)
print(p)
```

output

```
Parent(clazz_1={'name': 'jack', 'value': 12.5, 'description': 'desc1'}, clazz_2={'name': 'jim', 'value': 45.77, 'description': 'desc2'})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is not what I want to do.